# Please help to identify this component marked JC 5H on a Rockwell Automation power supply

Tags: diodes, identification, surface-mount

Please identify the component marked JC 5H on a power supply module from Rockwell Automation.

[image: photo of unknown component on a PCB]

Comment: What's the purpose of the component? What's the circuit around it look like? It's some type of diode, but we can't tell you more without some more information.

Comment: D17 stands for diode, and K stand for cathode.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a 100V 0.2A Schottky diode [NSR02100HT1](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NSR02100HT1-D.PDF)

[image]